# Visual SVN Server - projects storage location

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2008, visualsvn, visualsvn-server

I recently installed VisualSVN Server. I put Repository on `D:\Repositories` and added some projects to the repository via Visual Studio 2008.

`D:\Repositories\reponame` seems to be a little bit to small in size when comparing to my projects altogether.

I need to make sure where the projects are stored in order to make a backup when reinstalling system on my server. Any help with that would be appreciated.

Comment: This isn't a programming question and would, I feel, be better posed to the team behind the product. There is this helpful knowledge base article on their site: http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00012/

Comment: have you committed your project for the first time?

Comment: I think it is a valid (and useful) question. After all SubVersion is a product that a lot of developers use.

Comment: I think this is very programming related, and I see no harm in asking support style questions on SO as other people may have had related issues and be able to help faster than the official support team can.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Subversion is pretty thrifty when it comes to file space use.

You should have a set of folders under your D:\Repositories\reponame like "conf", "dav", "db", "hooks" and "locks".

under "db" I have "revprops", "revs" and "transactions".

If you commit a new file to the repository you should get a new entry in "revs" folder.

I use svn mirroring for my backups - mirror all repos to a different SVN server on a daily basis.

Liam

Answer (score 1):

IF you want to make sure you have your backups.  Create a new repository,  add some code and back up the folder structure.

Then delete it and restore it from backup.

SVN as Liam answered is very thrifty.